# SQL column subtraction of 2 other columns?

Tags: php, sql

Hello I have a online php SQL database and for that database let's say there are 2 columns they're both dates:

9/30/12
10/30/12 is there anyway I can create another column to subtract and get me the days between those 2? or would I have to do it via PHP and if it is by PHP how would I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**php way:**

for php 5.4+

```
echo (new \DateTime('9/30/12'))->diff((new \DateTime('10/30/12')))->format("%R%a days");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MySQL datediff() function.

Here is a link with more info:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp